# Is it possible to run a grails single grails unit test class from NetBeans?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, netbeans

I've been unable to find a way to run a single grails test class (which extend `GrailsUnitTestClass`) from the command line.  (I currently have a question out with a decent bounty, if you are interested.)

I'd be even happier if I could do the same from within NetBeans, but I haven't been able to do that either.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've removed my command-line specific answer, made it more robust, and added it to your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

known bug in Netbeans

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=159833

work around is documented here

http://www.troymaxventures.com/2009/06/quickly-running-single-grails-test-in.html